# Feed Streaming API Details to Visualforce Controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, streaming-api

Our sales managers want to buy a product called [Hoopla](https://www.hoopla.net/) but we don't have the budget, so I've been asked to build something in-house. The product does quite a bit, but the pieces they're most excited about are:

1. The ability to display a rotating series of dashboards
2. Notifications that interrupt the stream whenever a booking is closed

To try to deliver on these two features, I've built a series of VisualForce pages, each with an embedded Salesforce Analytics Dashboard. Every 60 seconds, I redirect to the next page in the series via Javascript.

I'm then using the streaming API to trigger a [confetti cannon](https://www.kirilv.com/canvas-confetti/) and a pop-up modal with the deal details every time an opportunity is closed (see mock-up below)

I've got everything working, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab related details like the Owner.Name. The Streaming API [doesn't support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/unsupported_soql_statements.htm) SOQL relationships, so while I have all of the details in the mock-up below, I have the Ids instead of the sObject names.

Other than redirecting to a new page outside of my flow with a GET variable opp Id in the redirect url, is there a way to dynamically send the streamed Opportunity Id to my visualforce controller so I can get the relationship details?

Ideally, this would be like an ajax call, so I don't have to refresh the page and/or exit my visualforce "app"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [Salesforce AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm) to hit the Salesforce API after receiving an inbound notification from the Streaming API. I could then grab any additional details I needed and add them to my page.